# Null Bytes disqualifying submissons

Tags: discussion, policy, answers

If a program prints out null bytes and those null bytes are not part of the specification, does this disqualify the program although these bytes are unreadable?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Yes

When a challenge states to output a specific sequence of bytes (such as `Hello, World!`), outputting anything else than that exact sequence of bytes is failing to meet the challenge specification. If you can encode the required output in a (pre-existing) encoding such that it matches the output of the submission (comparing raw bytes), it's valid.

Comment: Unless you can say you are using other encoding.

Comment: @Qwertiy The encoding doesn't matter very much. If you produce an output that is not exactly the same as the required output, it's not valid. Byte-level comparisons just make it easier - encode the output and the requirement in the same encoding, and compare the bytes.

Comment: If I have to output `Hello, World!`, but the real output as a byte sequence is `"\0H\0e\0l\0l\0o\0,\0 \0W\0o\0r\0l\0d\0!"` I can say that it is `Hello, World!` in UTF16. If it is saved to file and then opend, it is exactly valid result. But `\0Hello, World!` wouldn't be valid as there is no encoding we can look it in to match the required text.

Comment: @Qwertiy Precisely. That still is covered by this answer. Like I said, if you can encode the required output in a (pre-existing) encoding such that it matches the output of the submission (byte comparison), it's valid.